# How to select all the inputs not being descendants of particular elements?

Tags: jquery

Observe:

[image]

There are 275 elements on my page, of which 30 are inputs. 12 of the inputs are descendants of `tr.items` elements and consequently there are 18 inputs, which are not. How can I select the latter?

As you can see `$(:not(tr.items) input)` selects all the inputs.

Comment: Indeed, I must have missed that one - voted to close.

Comment: I see my answer is derivative from that question's accepted answer as well. I cannot claim originality as I've seen the `:not` selector being applied for these situations countless of times. However, closing a question which has an accepted answer doesn't do much besides adding an ugly banner to it, so I'll save my close votes for where it's more needed. `=]`

Comment: Does one have a quota on the close votes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('input:not(tr.items input)')
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/NhXYf/)

My selector matches all inputs which do not match `tr.items input`. Simply put, it selects all inputs which aren't descendant of `tr.items`.

[`:not(selector)` Reference](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
$('input').filter(function(){
   return $(this).closest('tr.items').length === 0
})
```

Comment: Nice, I got started tinkering with `.filter` but you beat me to it. +1

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var notwanted = $('tr.items').find('input');

var wanted =  $('input').not(notwanted);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var textinputs=$('input:text').map(function(){
   if($(this).parents('tr.items').length == 0){
    return $(this);
   } else {
    return null;
   }
 })
```

This will return an array-like object of those elements.  You could also use $.each;